# Top white bar appearing when converted from Bootstrap to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

There is a white bar at the top of a WordPress site when converted from Bootstrap.

- Bootstrap site: http://www.aktcs.com/aktcs/
- Wordpress site: http://www.aktcs.com/

It uses the latest WordPress release and the Twenty Nineteen theme. I cannot find the CSS causing this white background to appear.

Comment: I see a few differences between the 2 pages like slider height but no white bar on top. When you are connected, WP adminbar creates a margin on the top of the page. If you tryed to hide it perhaps is it where you see the top white bar. Try to disconnect and see if white bar still here.

Comment: I sorted out the problem.

Comment: can you tell how you solved the problem for my own curiosity and for community?

Comment: .entry-content {padding:0 !important;}
.entry-header {height:0 !important; padding:0 !important;}
.entry-content p:first-child { padding:0 !important; margin:0 !important;}